# date-fns showing invalid interval when comparing dates using isWithinInterval and a users timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, date-fns, date-fns-tz

I am getting back UTC time from an API, so in my next project, i am converting the UTC times to the users local time based on a timezone setting coming also from the API.

I am trying to use the `isWithinInterval` function of `date-fns` to check if the current time (in that users timezone) is within a start and end time, but it keeps throwing back a

`invalid interval`

At the top of the file, i am declaring the current time based on timezone;

```
const nowInUsersTimezone = new Date().toLocaleString('en-AU', { timeZone: user.timezone })
```

When i console log this, it shows perfect.

When i got to use the `isWithinInterval` im using the following to check if the `nowInUsersTimezone` is between 2 dates, if it is, then i just print `within`, but i cant get it to work;

```
{
    isWithinInterval(
        parseISO(nowInUsersTimezone),
        {
            start: parseISO(formatInTimeZone(job.start_time, user.timezone, 'dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm:ss aaa')),
            end: parseISO(formatInTimeZone(job.end_time, user.timezone, 'dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm:ss aaa')),
        }
    ) && (
        <>
            <p>Within</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

console logging the `start` and `end` dates works perfect, just when its in the `isWithinInterval` doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started) the `isWithinInterval` function from `date-fns` library checks if a date is within a given interval. It expects Date objects as arguments, not ISO strings.

The `toLocaleString` method returns a string, not a Date object, and the format of this string depends on the locale.

I would suggest using `parseISO` with ISO strings. But `new Date()` with a timezone conversion does not return an ISO string. That's likely why you're getting the "Invalid Interval" error.

**Heres how i would do it**:

```
const now = new Date();
const nowInUsersTimezone = new Date(
  now.toLocaleString('en-AU', { timeZone: user.timezone })
);

const jobStart = new Date(
  job.start_time.toLocaleString('en-AU', { timeZone: user.timezone })
);
const jobEnd = new Date(
  job.end_time.toLocaleString('en-AU', { timeZone: user.timezone })
);

{
  isWithinInterval(nowInUsersTimezone, {
    start: jobStart,
    end: jobEnd,
  }) && (
    <>
      <p>Within</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

**EDIT: Changed approach**

It sounds like the issue is not with the `isWithinInterval` function itself, but rather with the comparison of times. The first thing to check is whether the start time is earlier than the end time, and that `nowInUsersTimezone` is in between these two times.

```js
const user = {
  timezone: 'Australia/Sydney' //Example set
};

const job = {
  start_time: new Date('2023-07-29T00:00:00Z'), 
  end_time: new Date('2023-07-29T23:59:59Z'),
};


// create a new date object for the current time
const now = new Date();

// convert it to the user's timezone
const nowInUsersTimezone = new Date(now.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: user.timezone }));

// convert job start and end times to the user's timezone
const jobStart = new Date(job.start_time.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: user.timezone }));
const jobEnd = new Date(job.end_time.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: user.timezone }));

// check the interval
if(isWithinInterval(nowInUsersTimezone, { start: jobStart, end: jobEnd })) {
    console.log("Within");
} else {
    console.log("Not within");
}

console.log("Now in user's timezone: ", nowInUsersTimezone);
console.log("Job start time in user's timezone: ", jobStart);
console.log("Job end time in user's timezone: ", jobEnd);
```

Comment: That got rid of the errors, but it doesnt display with Within ... If i add a if else with within or not within is always displays not within

Comment: @CodeSauce -try now. You may have to provide more code to diagnose this further

Comment: Ahhhh ... The console log is showing; `Now in user's timezone:  Invalid Date` ... but if i console.log(user.timezone) it shows the correect timezone

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhh it looks like changing it from `en-US` to `en-AU` broke it ... I change is back and they are now returning

Comment: @CodeSauce The timezone value `en-AU` is a locale, not a timezone. Timezones typically take the form of "Continent/City", such as "Australia/Sydney".

Comment: Well that makes sense hahah a .... Thank you so much for all your help, its working great now